# DbContext get's disposed within using region

Tags: c#, dbcontext, dispose, using, invalidoperationexception

I just found out that when I try to use the `.Add()` method on a DbSet in my DbContext I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

This stack trace brought me back to line 238 of this method:
[image: Method]

Now it is true that this method uses two other methods (`CheckForBleKeyInDb` and `CheckForMpSwitchInDb`) which use their own `using(_db = new BeheerContext())` but this doesn't generate any errors for some reason.

The test variables don't generate any exceptions probably because they don't actually connect to the database, at least that is my guess.

I would like to know what exactly causes this exception and how I can prevent it.

Comment: You need to assign db locally. it is in fact those other methods that are disposing the db and dbset. You need to provide actual code as a [mcve] and not use a picture. They are not much help for use to better assess the problem

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the context as field in your class, then all methods share it and will dispose it at the end of their using statements.

> Now it is true that this method uses two other methods
>   (`CheckForBleKeyInDb` and `CheckForMpSwitchInDb`) which use their own
>   `using(_db = new BeheerContext())` but this doesn't generate any errors
>   for some reason.

So after the first call of those methods your context is disposed too.

Instead create them in the method(`var _db = ...`):

```
using(var _db = new BeheerContext())
{
   //...
}
```

Your test variables don't generate exceptions because they don't select from the tables. You would get the same exception if you'd for example use

```
var test1 = _db.BleKeys.First();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out any sub `using` in the sub calls. The architecture of the system doesn't know that you want to use something after it goes out of a *scope*. Find the offending `usings` and remove them and only have the overall `using` to do the work.